# Why is Diarrhoea (or, Diarrhea) not classified as a Vector-borne disease?

Tags: food-safety, disease-transmission, disease

I was reading that diseases such as Cholera & Typhoid are Vector-borne diseases wherein the Vector transfer the harmful bacteria to contaminate our food/water, causing the disease in humans.

By the same analogy, Diarrhoea (or, Diarrhea) too is caused when Rotavirus contaminates one's food/water. And obviously some agent (vector) would be needed to carry the Rotavirus to that food/water. Then why isn't Diarrhoea too classified as a vector-borne disease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*While I do agree with previous answer suggesting that diarrhea is a symptom rather than a disease, I would like to add the following:*

According to the WHO, diarrhea is defined as

> the passage of three or more loose or liquid stools per day (or more
>   frequent passage than is normal for the individual).

**While, infectious causes (virus, bacteria, parasite) are the most frequent aetiologies for diarrhea, other conditions can lead to diarrhea such as**:

- drugs (laxatives, antibiotics) that lead to an inflammation of the
  mucosa and therefore to an alteration in liquid absorption/secretion 
  in the intestine
- inflammatory bowel diseases
- neoplasia (colon cancer)
- malabsorption diseases such as celiac disease

*References:*

- http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs330/en/
- Toronto Notes 2015, FM26, "Diarrhea"

Answer (score 2):

I would assume because it is a symptom, not virus, bacteria, condition, etc, and a symptom is not the same as a disease.